# use redis hash consume more memory than key-value pair

Tags: redis

My raw data file is only 600mb.

I was using

```
hmset "10000000" "0427" "a long string" 
hmset "10000000" "0428" "a long string"
hmset "10000001" "0427" "a long string" 
hmset "10000001" "0429" "a long string"
```

the first one is user id, the second one is date, the third one is a long string.

Loading entire file into the memory takes 1.3gb.

If I only use

```
set "1000000000427" "a long string", 
set "1000000000428" "a long string", 
set "1000000010427" "a long string",
set "1000000000429" "a long string",
```

it only takes 800mb. Any idea how to save some spaces ?

Answer (score 0):

All of the redis data types are powerful. but you should choose the best way of use them. 
using of hashes can increase or decrease used memory. Its exactly depends on what you looking for.

For your case, i imagine you want to save the information of users, if its and if you ready to consume more times, I recommend you to use LIST

Why?

Hash use more memory for storing keys, while its the same for all users - such as username, name, age, date and ...

You can use a list instead, just with the little cheat. list are the sequence of items and you can access to each item by its index. 
You can use this index for storing information of user. for example first item is username, second is name and ....

This will reduce used memory, specifically